# When I project the QR code to the camera in OpenCV, an error occurs

Tags: c++, opencv, qr-code

I want to generate a code so that the video plays when the QR code is pointed at the camera.
But I get an error in warpPerspective.
The error is: OpenCV(4.5.3) Error: Assertion failed (_src.total() > 0) in cv::warpPerspective, file C:\build\master_winpack-build-win64-vc15\opencv\modules\imgproc \src\imgwarp.cpp, line 3144
I've searched in many places, but I can't find an answer, so I'm asking.

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void main() 
{
    Mat cameraFrame, videoFrame;
    vector<Point2f> bbox;
    double width, height;
    VideoCapture camera(0), video;
    QRCodeDetector qrDecoder;
    string data;
    
    while (camera.read(cameraFrame))
    {
        data = qrDecoder.detectAndDecode(cameraFrame, bbox);

        if (data.length() > 0)
        {
            if (!video.isOpened()) {
                video.open("../data/"+data+".mp4");
                width = video.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
                height = video.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
            }
            
            vector<Point2f> v_bbox{ Point2f(0, 0), Point2f(width,0), Point2f(width,height), Point2f(0, height) };
            Mat H = findHomography(v_bbox, bbox);
            video >> videoFrame;
            Mat warpedFrame, warpedMask;

            warpedFrame.copyTo(cameraFrame, warpedMask);

            warpPerspective(videoFrame, warpedFrame, H, cameraFrame.size());
            Mat mask(videoFrame.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(255));
            
            warpPerspective(mask, warpedMask, H, cameraFrame.size());
            imshow("warepedFrame", warpedFrame);
            imshow("WarpedMask", warpedMask);
        }
        imshow("cam", cameraFrame);
        waitKey(1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you call the *copyTo* method before *warpedFrame* is filled by *warpPerspective* which resets the *cameraFrame* mat, then when you pass *cameraFrame.size()* to
*warpPerspective* and construct the mask mat using *cameraFrame.size()* you basically pass a size of (0,0)

all you have to do is to copy the wrapped video overlay after you apply the perspective transformations:

```
#include "opencv2/opencv.hpp"

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

void main() 
{
    Mat cameraFrame, videoFrame;
    vector<Point2f> bbox;
    double width, height;
    VideoCapture camera(0), video;
    QRCodeDetector qrDecoder;
    string data;
    
    while (camera.read(cameraFrame))
    {
        data = qrDecoder.detectAndDecode(cameraFrame, bbox);

        if (data.length() > 0)
        {
            if (!video.isOpened()) {
                video.open("../data/"+data+".mp4");
                width = video.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH);
                height = video.get(CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT);
            }
            
            vector<Point2f> v_bbox{ Point2f(0, 0), Point2f(width,0), Point2f(width,height), Point2f(0, height) };
            Mat H = findHomography(v_bbox, bbox);
            video >> videoFrame;
            Mat warpedFrame, warpedMask;
    
            warpPerspective(videoFrame, warpedFrame, H, cameraFrame.size());
            Mat mask(videoFrame.size(), CV_8UC1, cv::Scalar(255));
            
            warpPerspective(mask, warpedMask, H, cameraFrame.size());

            imshow("warepedFrame", warpedFrame);
            imshow("WarpedMask", warpedMask);

            warpedFrame.copyTo(cameraFrame, warpedMask);

        }
        imshow("cam", cameraFrame);
        waitKey(1);
    }
}
```